# Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero elements of the Unique Factorization Domain R. Prove that $a$ and $b$ have a least common multiple

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero elements of the Unique Factorization Domain R. Prove that $a$ and $b$ have a least common multiple and describe it in terms of the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$.

**attempt:** Recall by definition , a least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is an element $e$ of $R$ (commutative ring with 1) such that $a|e$ and $b|e$, and 2) if $a|e'$ and $b|e'$ then $e|e'$.

This least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ (if such exists) is a generator for the unique largest principal ideal contained in $(a) \cap (b)$.

Recall that every principal ideal domain is a unique factorization domain.
I actually proved in another exercise that : any two nonzero elements of a P.I.D. have a least common multiple.

So I was wondering if I can use the same argument that any two nonzero elements of a P.I.D. have a least common multiple. Since P.I.D implies U.D.F , would I be able to conclude the proof?

In addition, the describe least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ ....

let $a$ and $b$ be two nonzero elements of the Unique Factorization Domain $R$ and suppose

$a = up_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}....p_n^{e_n} $
 and $b = vp_1^{f_1}p_2^{f_2}....p_n^{f_n} $ are prime factorizations for $a$ and $b$, where $u$ and $v$ are units, the primes $p_1,p_2,....,p_n$ are distinct and the exponents $e_i$ and $f_i$ are $\geq$ 0. Then the element

$l = p_1^{max(e_1,f_1)}p_2^{max(e_2,f_2)}....p_n^{max(e_n,f_n)}$.

is a least common multiple of $a$ and $b$.

can someone please verify this? any suggestion or better approach would really help. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use the result for PIDs, since there are UFDs that are not PIDs.  Your approach to describe the least common multiple is a good one to show that the least common multiple exists.